# Vagrant + VirtualBox + X11 on a headless server

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, x11, headless

I'm trying to run a `VirtualBox` Ubuntu VM via `Vagrant` on a headless server. 
The VM has `ubuntu-desktop package` installed, however when the machine boots up I can't open X applications. DISPLAY environment is empty and setting it to ":0" doesn't help.

I know there is an option to start VirtualBox in non-headless mode (`vb.gui = true`), however I'm unable to perform `vagrant up` with that option turned on, unless I connect to the sever with X forwarding turned on (the server I run `Vagrant` on is headless).

Am I missing something? When I do ssh X tunnelling all the way down to the VM, it works, but then I guess the display will be set by ssh. 
What I wanted to achieve is a VM that can run x applications on it's internal ":0" screen. I don't need to see them, I need to be able to execute X applications remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a very useful thread [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/449055-headless-x-server-linux/) based on which I believe I know how to make this working.

It seems like it should be enough to just run Xvfb and then setup the DISPLAY environment variable accordingly before running the X application of interest. 
A way to check if it's working is to use x11vnc and connect over VNC to the server.